# Navigating from current location to dropped pin

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a Map View with a dropped pin inside it , what i would like to do is to show a route from the user current location to the dropped pin.

I searched for it but with no luck, if someone know a way to do it please help ? :)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it....

You can do it using two ways :
1.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { c_lat, c_long };
CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = { [[dic valueForKey:@"business_lat"]doubleValue], [[dic valueForKey:@"business_long"]doubleValue] };

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&",start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

2.

Using Google [API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling)

Please check [this](http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/draw-route-between-two-location/) for draw route between two location

In API you just need to pass origin name and destination name

Hope i helped....

Comment: @aLFaRSi : yes, you need to use second option just use google api and parse responce and set data according your choise.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do it ? :)

Comment: it's complex but you can do it by parse response.